# Understanding an equality

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I need to understand why this is true because it is a given to a proof on why f(x)= $\sqrt x$ continuous on [0,∞).

|√x −√y| ≤ |√x + √y|

Thanks

Comment: They are positive. |a-b| = either a-b or b-a < = b+a =|a+b|

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\sqrt{x} \geq 0 \; \forall x \geq 0$.
So $$ \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y} \leq \sqrt {x} \leq \sqrt {x} + \sqrt {y} \\ = |\sqrt {x} + \sqrt {y}|$$
and
$$\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x} \leq \sqrt {y} \leq \sqrt {y} + \sqrt {x} \\ = |\sqrt {y} + \sqrt {x}|$$
Therefore,
$$|\sqrt {x}-\sqrt {y}| \leq |\sqrt {x}+\sqrt {y}|.$$